# ¿Como puedo obtener la ultima fecha de actualización de un fichero mío en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, date, update

Tengo un fichero subido a un servidor, y es en formato Excel, y me gustaría saber cual es la ultima fecha de actualización de este fichero, usando javascript, porque con angular no creo que se pueda hacer nada.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes control sobre el servidor donde está ubicada esa excel te recomendaría que desarrollases algún tipo de función servidora a la que pudieras consultar esa información ya que sería la forma más robusta de obtener la información.

En caso contrario podrías tratar de aprovecharte del campo [Last-Modified](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) de HTTP. Enviando una petición HTTP de tipo HEAD que se comporta igual que GET pero solo devuelve las cabeceras y no el contenido del fichero puedes implementar un código javascript que obtenga esa información.

Ejemplo de código javascript para leer el campo Last-Modified de un archivo:

```
var url = "http://direccionweb/archivo.xls";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("HEAD", url);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
       console.log(xhr.status);
       console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"))
    }};

xhr.send();
```

Ejemplo de petición Head de un archivo xltx de la página de Microsoft:
[image: Ejemplo petición head]

Nota: El uso del campo Last-Modified puede no ser fiable si el recurso que se consulta se genera dinámicamente o según el tipo de servidor.

Comment: En el ultimo caso que me comentas no me funciona, si que se en que ruta del servidor se encuentra, ya que esta en un servidor ftp y controlo su ruta, pero no se como implementar una función servidora de esa info

Comment: @Omega_skyres9 Buenas, parece que por lo que cuentas el ftp no te ofrece una forma de obtener los archivos vía HTTP por lo que el método que te comentaba no funciona. Las comunicaciones FTP y HTTP son protocolos distintos por lo que para hacer una función servidora que obtenga esos datos necesitarías disponer de un php, o api de .net o similar. Te dejo links de funciones útiles para php: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filemtime.php y net: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebresponse.lastmodified?view=net-5.0 Espero que te ayuden.